# WordPress editing php get_template_part() and get_post_format() function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to load the post content only with no title, date, comment, etc info. Is there a way to grab the post only?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply replace:

```
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

With:

```
    <?php the_content(); ?>
```

The former is looking for something like **content-status.php** or **content-aside.php** or most likely, in the case of a plain old 'post', **content.php** in your theme root.

Answer (score 8):

You can replace

```
 <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

with

```
 <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'myformat' ); ?>
```

and edit a copy of `content-page.php` with name `content-myformat.php` where you can remove `the_title()` row.